# CSS3 Make Text As Big As Possible To FIll Element Without Overflowing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm building a phonegap app for IOS, and I have one `<p>` tag who's contents must be exactly one line across.

These elements have the full width of the device minus a little outer padding.  What I want is for the text to scale to as large a font-size as possible without wrapping to next line, without being cutoff by ellipsis or being clipped, or overflowing.

So far I can accomplish this by precisely setting the font-size (which can be done - there are only about 10 devices to think about), but I'd rather have IOS UIWeview display figure it out for me.

Is it possible to achieve this with CSS?

Comment: not possible with vanilla CSS; you'll have to use JavaScript.

Comment: If you sure about that, you should post it as an answer, and if no one else offers something better, I'll vote for it, since you caught it first.

Comment: http://fittextjs.com/ (I'm kind of rushed so don't have time to make a fully fleshed out answer.)

Comment: Fittextjs.com isn't centered on my mobile Chrome browser.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/462sh7ti5/

Comment: It's centered for me on Chrome in iOS. Looks like your browser isn't interpreting the custom font which is why it's not centering. http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/5306/xl30.jpg

Comment: also fittextjs allows for 'compression' so you can modify to achieve the proper fit.  Good little library.

Answer (score 3):

With CSS only, you can achieve this using *Viewport Units* by setting the font-size to fill up the space, but now with the text size responsive based on the viewport's width.

```
p {
    font-size: 7vw; //set to the preferred size based on length of text
}
```

Here is a simple demo using vw units: https://jsfiddle.net/gmattucc/mh3rsr0o/

You would have to check if vw, vh units are supported in the device you are targeting: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

You might also want to check out this article to learn more: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: This is definitely the answer nowadays.  Unfortunately it wasn't when I posted it.  Thanks :)

Comment: Didn't see how old his post is haha :)