# Make monospaced text as big as possible without causing overflow or wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size, monospace

I'm looking for a way to make a monospaced text as wide as possible in its container witohut overflowing or breaking. I've already looked at [CSS3 Make Text As Big As Possible To FIll Element Without Overflowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554967/css3-make-text-as-big-as-possible-to-fill-element-without-overflowing) and tried to implement the suggested solution, but it doesn't appear to work in my case. If I set the font size to `3vw` instead of `7vw` as suggested in the answer to the linked question, it seems to be close, but when I change the length of the lines or width of the page, it's off again.

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/de7qbu19/ (the code in the fiddle is the same)

```css
#song-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
}
#song {
    color: #000;
    font: normal 3vw Courier New,monospace,Courier;
    white-space: pre;
    word-break: break-all;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#song > span { /* Chords*/
    color: #007fbf;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="song-container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <span id="song">
[Placeholder]

<span>Em</span>         <span>G</span>
Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder
<span>D</span>          <span>C</span>
Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run the snippet it seems like it almost takes the entire width:
[image: small]
But when I then click the `Full page` option, it becomes clear that it doesn't and that it's not reliable, especially when I reduce the window size:
[image: full screen small win]

So setting the font size using the `vw` units doesn't appear to do the trick for me.

Any ideas how I could achieve this properly?

Comment: Sounds like you need another class? Like `.text.full-page` or `.text.small-page` and throw your styles under those. So you would define two separate `font-sizes` based on the current setting. Maybe also look at media queries if your screen size is actually shrinking?

Comment: Are you suggesting to create hundreds of media query entries and find out via trial and error which screen width requires which font size to cover every resolution/zoom state? Sounds like a lot of work and not very maintainable. Just changing the font type would break everything wouldn't it?

Comment: No I wouldn't advocate that, it sounded like you only had 2 or so views that were breaking which would be ok for that. Have you taken a look at this https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/

Some options to achieve what you're looking for

Comment: None of those worked for me. Either they only work with one line of text or you have to change some value whenever the length of the text lines changes or it just doesn't work with all window sizes.

Comment: It is `margin: 20px;` causing the trouble. Change the value to `margin: 20px auto;` may resolve your issue.

Comment: @7cc I just tried that and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @Forivin plz try at https://fiddle.jshell.net/de7qbu19/show/ or local html file, not in iframe here. But if you plan to use the page in iframe, then add `#song-container { width: min-content }`

Comment: @7cc Doesn't work for me. When I reduce the windows width and zoom in it breaks just like in the screenshot of my question.

Comment: @Forivin I can reproduce that only when the developer tool is opening or by increasing padding of .panel-body [screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/IPSJdYZ) (I mean I cannot reduce the windows width that much without effort).

BTW, please keep in mind that css-based (and some js-based) answers work only when characters have the same width.
Normally CJK characters/emoji have different width, though you may not use them for chords.

Answer (score 3):

If you're fine width a javascript solution, here's a simple one.

It consist in retrieving the width of div and font size, it calculates the width of a single character, and finally calculates the new maximum font size according to these informations.

You must also specify in the script the maximum number of characters you can have on the longest line of text:

```
Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder
```

> In this example above, there are 47 characters on the longest line of text;

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container"),
  cs = getComputedStyle(container),
  containerPB = parseFloat(cs.paddingLeft) + parseFloat(cs.paddingRight) + parseFloat(cs.borderLeftWidth) + parseFloat(cs.borderRightWidth), //containerPadding + containerBorderWidth
  containerWidth = container.offsetWidth - containerPB,
  containerFontSize = parseFloat(cs.fontSize),
  containerFontFamily = cs.fontFamily,
  span = document.createElement("SPAN"),
  char = document.createTextNode("a"),
  charMax = 47, //max characters per line
  alpha = 1.00; //represent font scaling based on width
span.style.fontFamily = containerFontFamily;
span.appendChild(char);
span.style.visibility = "hidden";
document.body.appendChild(span);
//GETTING THE WIDTH OF A SINGLE CHAR
var charWidth = span.getBoundingClientRect().width;
document.body.removeChild(span);
container.style.fontSize =
  (containerWidth * containerFontSize * alpha) / (charWidth * charMax) + "px";
window.addEventListener("resize", function(e) {
  //update the width of container
  containerWidth = container.offsetWidth - containerPB;
  //update the font-size
  container.style.fontSize =
    (containerWidth * containerFontSize * alpha) / (charWidth * charMax) + "px";
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Courier New, monospace, Courier;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.375rem;
  width: 90%;
}

#container>span {
  /* Chords*/
  color: #007fbf;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<pre id="container">[Placeholder]

<span>Em</span>         <span>G</span>
Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder
<span>D</span>          <span>C</span>
Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's first have a look at why the size of the text is the way it currently is. `3vw` means `3%` of the viewport width. **Important to note is that this value is used for the height of the characters.** We can calculate the width of the full text in a percentage of the viewport width. **This only works for a mono font.**

To start of we need the width/height ration of the font. The width of a mono-spaced character depends on the font. I will be working with `Courier New` for this example. I'm not sure where exactly to find this so I will be using a approximate of `99/188`.

[image: image of character measurement]

If the maximum amount of characters is:

```
11 * 4 (Placeholder) + 3 (spaces) = 47
```

Then the width of 47 characters is:

```
47 * 3vw * (99/188) = 74.25vw
```

So about `75%` of the viewport width. This means when paddings, margins and borders take up more then `25%` of the width (due to resizing the window) the contents of the text will no longer fit in its container.

So how do we make the content fit? We can use the CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to subtract some a static value from a dynamic value. To do this we first have to know the width of the static values. In your example these are the static widths:

- `20px` margin for `#song-container`
- `15px` padding for `.container-fluid`
- `1px` border for `.panel`
- `15px` padding for `.panel-body`

Don't forget that all of these values are present on both sides, so they take up:

```
(20px + 15px + 1px + 15px) * 2 = 102px
```

We **can't** subtract this from the `3vw`, because the `3vw` is the height of one character whereas the `102px` is the width of the static elements. So we now need to convert the `102px` to the height of one character. This is done by spreading the width over all characters, then applying the ratio to convert from character width to height.

```
102px / 47 / (99/188) ≈ 4.121212121
```

Now we are comparing apples with apples and we can use `calc(3vw - 102px / 47 / (99/188))` for the font size. You can now freely play around with the `3vw` value. In the example I upped this value to `3.5vw`.

Note that this isn't 100% accurate, I didn't account for character spacing and the font width/height ratio is based on a measurement, not a given.

```css
#song-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
}
#song {
    color: #000;
    font-size: calc(3.5vw - 102px / 47 / (99/188));
    font-family: "Courier New",monospace,Courier;
    white-space: pre;
    word-break: break-all;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#song > span { /* Chords*/
    color: #007fbf;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="song-container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <span id="song">
[Placeholder]

<span>Em</span>         <span>G</span>
Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder
<span>D</span>          <span>C</span>
Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works, but when the static widths, the maximum amount of characters or the font width/height ratio changes you have to recalculate the compensation value. For this reason a JavaScript library might be better suited. You can find a few of them described in the CSS-Trics post [Fitting Text to a Container](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/).

I would also suggest taking a look at the [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16056591/3982562) question, which has some other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I few things that will improve the responsiveness is this:

```
#song-container{
 text-align: center;
 margin:0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-body{
 margin: 0;
}
```

If you would like the overflow to be scrollable you can just add `overflow-x: scroll;` Also if you use media queries that would make it more responsive as well because even with my approach there it comes to a point that if the screen is only 220px it will cut some of the words due to the fonts not scalling fast enough, which you could alter your media query to scale the font faster after reaching this point to keep it within your container.
Hope this helps!

EDIT:

```
  #song-container {
    text-align: center;
    /*margin: 20px;*/
    padding: 1%;
}
#song {
    color: #000;
    font: normal 3vw Courier New,monospace,Courier;
    white-space: pre;
    word-break: break-all;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#song > span { /* Chords*/
    color: #007fbf;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.panel-body{
  padding:0;
}
```

This should do it, I edit it in the fiddle.

Comment: JSFiddle forks the project when you are not the owner, generating a new URL. So you either have to link to the new URL from your answer, or press the large "Copy snippet to answer" button under the snippet and make the edits here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Gotcha, I did not know that Thanks! However when I mean I edit the fiddle I meant that I tested it there and just copied the code, my apologies if that was misleading.